# Is there a way to update the image used by node in slurm-gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, slurm

I installed slurm-gcp from that github using terraform in cloud shell.

https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm-gcp#install-using-terraform

There are two VMs created.

- controller
- login

I installed several applications in /apps to confirm that they exist.

I would like to edit node's /etc/hosts and add network tag (http-server, https-server) to run the applications.

But nowhere does it say how to modify the image used by node .

Is there no way to edit the image of the slurm?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the latest version of Slurm on GCP, the images are pre-built and hosted by SchedMD, and are used directly without the requirement to make build an image at deployment time. You can continue to modify the image by [creating your own image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images). This is done by spinning up a VM with the public image pointed to in the tfvars, making your modifications, saving the image, and pointing your tfvars to your new image.

You can continue to use the [custom compute/controller install scripts](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm-gcp/tree/master/scripts) found in the scripts directory.